# Tests pass on local AS emulator but fail on Firebase test-lab

Tags: android, firebase, automated-tests, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have the following piece of code which is:

- click a toggle from Firefox app
- the toggle opens the Default apps menu from System settings
- I open the browser list, pick my browser and return to the app by pressing back.

This part works fine in my local Android studio emulator and real device, but when I run it on Firebase test lab with the same virtual device configuration: Pixel 2 API 28, it will not detect the "Browser app" text and fail.

Any ideas why it behaves differently on the Firebase virtual device?

````
fun selectDefaultBrowser() {
        clickSetDefaultBrowserToggle()
        mDevice.waitNotNull(
               Until.findObject(By.text("Browser app")),
               TestAssetHelper.waitingTime
            )
         assertAndroidSettingsPackage()
         defaultBrowserAppList().waitForExists(waitingTime)
         defaultBrowserAppList().clickAndWaitForNewWindow()
         fenixDebugOption().click()
         mDevice.pressBack()
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mDevice.pressBack()
         }
     }

    fun clickSetDefaultBrowserToggle() =
        setDefaultBrowserToggle().clickAndWaitForNewWindow()

    fun setDefaultBrowserToggle() = mDevice.findObject(
          UiSelector().resourceId("org.mozilla.fenix.debug:id/switch_widget")
    )

    fun defaultBrowserAppList() = mDevice.findObject(
       (UiSelector()
           .className("android.widget.TextView"))
           .resourceId("android:id/title")
           .text("Browser app")
    )

    fun assertAndroidSettingsPackage() = assertTrue(
        mDevice.findObject(
            (UiSelector().packageName("com.android.settings"))
        ).waitForExists(waitingTime)
    )

    fun fenixDebugOption() = mDevice.findObject(UiSelector().text("Firefox Preview"))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.
This is not enough: fun defaultBrowserAppList() = mDevice.findObject((UiSelector().text("Browser app")). For some reason it doesn't match the text.

Should be replaced with UiSelector().textContains("Browser app") and then it works (ignores caps/non-caps).
Same for: mDevice.findObject(UiSelector().textContains("Firefox Preview"))